# Problem with multiple themes deploy in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line, static-content-deploy

When I execute CLI command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. It always has only 4 steps themes, but now I have multiple duplicate themes while running the command.

```
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2631/2631           ============================ 100%   < 1 sec          
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2709/2709           ============================ 100%   0                
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2648/2648           ============================ 100%   1 sec            
frontend/Meigee/sirena/en_US            2925/2925           ============================ 100%   12 secs
```

I will be grateful for the hint! Why my themes are duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created theme with any parent theme which is mentioned in app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/theme.xml in  node.

So when you do **setup:static-content:deploy**, first it will do deploy for parent theme and then for child theme.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But Problem is not a correlation between parent and child theme. Problem concerns a multiple the same themes deploy.